# Facing difficulty in creating x-path

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using JAVA Selenium-3 facing issue to create a x-path,
the DOM structure is as follow,

[image]

In this DOM

```
<span class="ant-table-column-title" xpath="1">Inspection_Status</span>
```

is a column name.

and

```
<svg fill="currentColor" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" height="1em" width="1em" viewBox="0 0 40 40" type="filter" class="ant-table-filter-icon custom-table-filter-icon ant-dropdown-trigger" title="Filter menu" style="vertical-align: middle; color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" xpath="3">
```

is a drop-down I want to click the drop-down.

I have created the xpath:

```
1. //th[6]//*[@title='Filter menu']
2. //th[6]//*[local-name()='svg']
```

but
 I don't want to include the tag 'th' in x-path
 because there are multiple 'th' tag and column position is changing.
 If I get the xpath which include the column name that will be help full.

Note: The Column  and drop-down are connected, if column position is get hanged then drop-down position also changes with respect to column

Thank,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the reference of the `span column` if the `text` is `unique`.

```
//span[@class='ant-table-column-title' and text()='Inspection_Status']/ancestor::th[1]//*[local-name()='svg']
```

**Update**: try with [last()]

```
(//span[@class='ant-table-column-title' and text()='Inspection_Status']/ancestor::th[1]//*[local-name()='svg'])[last()]
```

Comment: The span column text is not having any unique value

Comment: @kunduK- I have updated the screen shot, it is having 3 'svg' tag, so with above xpath it is showing 3 matching elements, the main 'svg' tag is i have bordered in red color

Comment: @Girish : Just check the updated xpath and let me know the status?

Answer (score 0):

Please try below solution to click on svg element:

```
 //*[local-name()='svg']//*[name()='g']//*[name()='path']//ancestor::th[starts-with(@class,'ant-table-column-has-actions ant-table-column-has-filters')]//span[@class='ant-table-column-title']
```

Comment: it is not working, there are multiple columns which is having same structure. so the xpath is not unique one

Comment: please check updated solution if its working for you